# Text search for microservice architectures

Tags: elasticsearch, architecture, microservices

I am investigating into implementing text search on a microservice based system. We will have to search for data that span across more than one microservice.

E.g. say we have two services for managing Organisations and managing Contacts. We should be able to search for organisations by contact details in one search operation.

Our preferred search solution is Elasticsearch. We already have a working solution based on embedded objects (and/or parent-child) where when a parent domain is updated the indexing payload is enriched with the dependent object data, which is held in a cache (we avoid making calls to the service managing child directly for this purpose).

I am wondering if there is a better solution. Is there a microservice pattern applicable to such scenarios?

Answer (score 7):

It's not particularly a microservice pattern I would suggest you, but it fits perfectly into microservices and it's called **Event sourcing**

Event sourcing describes an architectural pattern in which events are generated by different sources. An event will now trigger 0 or more so called **Projections** which then use the data contained in the event to aggregate information in the form it is needed.

This is directly applicable to your problem: Whenever the organisation service changes it's internal state (Added / removed / updated an organization) it can fire an event. If an organization is added, it will for example aggregate the contacts to this organization and store this aggregate. The search for it is now trivial: Lookup the organizations id in the aggregated information (this can be indexed) and get back the contacts associated with this organization. Of course the same works if contracts are added to the contract service: It just fires a message with the contract creation information and the corresponding projections now alter different aggregates that can again be indexed and searched quickly.

You can have multiple projections responding to a single event - which enables you to aggregate information in many different forms - exactly the way you'd like to query it later. Don't be afraid of duplicated data: event sourcing takes this trade-off intentionally and since this is not the data your business-services rely on and you do not need to alter it manually - this duplication will not hurt you.

If you store the events in the chronological order they happened (which I seriously advise you to do!) You can 'replay' these events over and over again. This helps for example if a projection was buggy and has to be fixed!

If your're interested I suggest you read up on event sourcing and look for some kind of event store:

- [event sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)
- [event store](https://geteventstore.com)

We use event sourcing to aggregate an array of different searches in our system and we aggregate millons of records every day into mongodb. All projections have their own collection create their own indexes and until now we never had to resort to different systems / patterns like elastic search or the likes!

Let me know if this helped!

**Amendment**

> use the data contained in the event to aggregate information in the form it is needed

An event should contain all the information necessary to aggregate more information. For example if you have an organization creation event, you need to at least provide some information on what the organizations name is, an ID of some kind, creation date, parent organizations ID etc. As a rule of thumb, we send all the information we gather in the service that gets the request (don't take it directly form the request ;-) check it first, then write it to the event and send it off) because we do not know what we're gonna need in the future. Just stay cautious - payloads should not get too large!

We can now have multiple projections responding to this event: One that adds the organizations to it's parents aggregate (to get an easy lookup for all children of a given organization), one that just adds it to the search set of all organizations and maybe a third that aggregates all the parents of a given child organization so the lookup for the parent organizations is easy and fast.

We have the same service process these events that also process client requests. The motivation behind it is, that the schema of the data that your projections create is tightly coupled to the way it is read by the service that the client interacts with. This does not have to be that way and it could be separated into two services - but you create an almost invisible dependency there and releasing these two services independently becomes even more challenging. But if you do not mind that additional level of complexity - you can separate the two.

We're currently also considering writing a generic service for aggregating information from events for things like searches, where projections could be scripted. That only makes the *invisible dependencies problem* less conspicuous, it does not solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate the "use the data contained in the event to aggregate information in the form it is needed" bit. Do you use the same services used for servicing client requests for this aggregations?